# Notation for compact sets?

Tags: notation, compactness

Is there some accepted notation for a set that is compact?

E.g. I am currently writing "... [blah] is true if for **every compact set** $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and ...".

I could simplify my writing if there was some notation that meant the set $A$ is compact.

Thank you,

Comment: None that I am aware of, but I hope you are saying “for every compact set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$” rather than $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$...

Comment: Yes - thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 4):

$K$ is often used for compact sets, but (to my knowledge) there is no notation that definitively designates a set as compact. If you just said "for every $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n...$ the reader could not infer that $K$ is compact.

Comment: Sometimes typos are just that. Your answer is irrelevant now, after that has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo, but my answer is not irrelevant. It's still true that there is no accepted notation for a set that is compact.